# Heroku Postgres: Getting started in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, plugins, heroku

I am new to `Heroku` and trying to set up a simple trial application. I have installed the [Eclipse Heroku plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse) and have a simple Hello Heroku application running on [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Juno edition)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2).

I'd like to now incorporate some simple database functionality, probably with [Heroku PostGres](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql). The trouble is that all of the information I'm finding about how to do this is via the command line.

My question is, is there a way to incorporate `PostGres` via the Eclipse IDE? How would I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to provision a database through http://postgres.heroku.com directly or through http://dashboard.heroku.com. Once you've provisioned it you can get your configuration for the database by selecting the database from https://postgres.heroku.com/databases. Once you've selected it; it should display all of your connection information. You can then go into the data explorer view within eclipse and create a new connection to this database.